# Access many to many field from queryset Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class Vineyard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class WineRegion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    vineyards = models.ManyToManyField(Vineyard, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I want to access all vineyards from the wine region. Here is what I've tried:

```
if len(id_list) > 0:
    wr = WineRegion.objects.filter(id__in=id_list)
    vineyardList = wr.vineyards.all()
```

But it gives me an error ---> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'vineyards'

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

And what if I have another model called Country? Here is the model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    wine_rg = models.ManyToManyField(WineRegion, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to access all vineyards from the wine region, but now I have a list of Country IDs. How can I solve this?

I can do something like this:

```
wine_region_id = Country.objects.filter(id__in=country).distinct().values('wine_rg')
vineyardList = vineyardList.filter(wineregion__in=wine_region_id)
```

But I'm curious is there any better method to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `wr` is a list of `WineRegions`, you need to iterate through them first:

```py
vineyardList = []
for wr in WineRegion.objects.filter(id__in=id_list):
    for vineyard in wr.vineyards.all():
        vineyardList.append(vineyard)
```

But this will hit your db multiple times just to get each vineyard objects. Instead, you can access the related name `wineregion` from `Vineyard` to get all the vineyard objects in one query like this:

```
vineyardList = Vineyard.objects.filter(wineregion__in=WineRegion.objects.filter(id__in=id_list))
```

or simply:

```py
vineyardList = Vineyard.objects.filter(wineregion__in=id_list)
```

Comment: Thanks! but what if I have a parent to wine region called Country? Country has a foreign key field to wine region. And I also have a list of country IDs.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

vineyardList = Vineyard.objects.filter(country__wineregion__in=country)

Comment: Can you share your models? Maybe in a new question

Comment: Try `Vineyard.objects.filter(wineregion__country__in=country)`